# ADODB EXCEL SQL CopyFromRecordset to slow

Tags: sql, excel, sql-insert, adodb, recordset

I use VBA and ADODB Connection in Excel to realize VLOOKUP with SQL in attached code:
The Line "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("result").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs" takes to much time. Is there a way to use "INSERT INTO" in "strSQL" and skip  "copyfromrecordset" instead to speedup the makro?

```
Sub vlookup()

Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strConnection As String
Dim strSQL As String


Worksheets("result").UsedRange.Clear

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")

strConnection = "DRIVER={MICROSOFT EXCEL DRIVER (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}; DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName

With cn

    .Open strConnection
    strSQL = "SELECT table1$.*, table2$.price  FROM [table1$] LEFT JOIN [table2$] ON table1$.animal = table2$.animal"
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
    
    With rs
        .Source = strSQL
        .ActiveConnection = strConnection
        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
        .Open
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("result").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
        .Close
    End With
End With


cn.Close

Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
        

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this question while struggling with legacy code which had `CopyFromRecordSet`. In my experience, it is horribly slow for anything more than a trivial number of lines.

Try extracting the Recordset information into 2D Variant Array and set the Value property of the respective Excel Range. Chunk your data if you think memory is going to be a constraint. The solution is involved. You'll need to do the bounds checks and also transpose the data before setting the Value property. Full answer below (without chunking):

```
Sub CopyFromRecordset(rngStart As Range, rstData As Variant)
    Dim buffer As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    If InStr(TypeName(rstData), "RecordSet") > 0 Then
        rstData.MoveLast
        rstData.MoveFirst
        buffer = rstData.GetRows(rstData.RecordCount)
        ReDim buffer2(UBound(buffer, 2), UBound(buffer, 1)) As Variant
        For i = 0 To UBound(buffer, 1)
            For j = 0 To UBound(buffer, 2)
                buffer2(j, i) = buffer(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i
        rngStart.Application.Range(rngStart, rngStart.Offset(UBound(buffer2, 1), UBound(buffer2, 2))).Value = buffer2
    Else
        Debug.Print ("Expected RecordSet, found " & TypeName(rstData))
    End If
End Sub

Sub vlookup()

    Dim cn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strConnection As String
    Dim strSQL As String

    Worksheets("result").UsedRange.Clear
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.CONNECTION")
    strConnection = "DRIVER={MICROSOFT EXCEL DRIVER (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}; DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName

    With cn
        .Open strConnection
        strSQL = "SELECT table1$.*, table2$.price  FROM [table1$] LEFT JOIN [table2$] ON table1$.animal = table2$.animal"
        Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.RECORDSET")
    
        With rs
            .Source = strSQL
            .ActiveConnection = strConnection
            .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
            .LockType = adLockOptimistic
            .Open
            CopyFromRecordset ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("result").Range("A1"), rs
            .Close
        End With
    End With
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```